# Executing stored procedure with parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created the following stored procedure and it runs perfectly

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC sp_infoschemacolumns
    @COLUMN varchar(255),
    @DATA VARCHAR(255)
AS
    DECLARE @SQLString as varchar(255);
    SET @SQLSTRING = '

    SELECT * 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE @COLUMN = @DATA'

    EXEC(@sqlstring);
    RETURN;
GO
```

This is my exec command statement

```
DECLARE @COLUMN VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(255);

EXEC [dbo].[sp_infoschemacolumns] @COLUMN = "COLUMN_NAME", @DATA =  'LASTNAME';
```

When I run this it tells me to declare variable

Could you please help me with my exec statement?

Comment: Why did you put the SQL statement inside a string??? This defeats the purpose of using stored procedures in the first place. You don't need `EXEC` to execute the SELECT statement, it works the same as any other statement

Comment: In this case they "need" it in a string, because they want to pass in the column name. If they did not pass in the column name, it would be executed as a regular SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have variables in the SQL String inside the stored procedure that are not known, because they are inside a string.

See the following article for an in depth explanation.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/